# react tutorial first sentence, little bit strange

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am reading the tutorial on react: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#what-is-react

But the first sentence feels a little bit strange to me. And with the sentence I mean this sentence:

We will build a small game during this tutorial. You might be tempted to skip it because you’re not building games — but give it a chance.

So what does the writer mean with 'game' and 'games'?

I mean what is the difference?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English, not about programming. You might try [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) who should be able to tell you how to understand the sentence.

Comment: There is no difference between what the writer meant with `game` or `games`. They mean that in that tutorial they're building a `game`. But you might be tempted to skip the tutorial due to you not being a developer of `games`.

Comment: Ah, oké. Thank you for your explanation. Very nice. I didn't thought that way

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think he just means that you're not currently a game developer so building a game might seem irrelevant.